# Java XML Parsing Unexpected

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a normal xml file using java and trying to store the information in a Map. However, I am not able to make it behave as expected.

Kindly point me the issue which is causing this behavior.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <allnews>
    <news>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>I am news 1</title>
        <date>04-01-2018</date>
    </news>
    <news>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>I am news 2</title>
        <date>04-01-2018</date>
    </news>
    </allnews>
```

Java File:

```
public class readxml {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("D:/Aadil/CAPS_Workspace/samp/src/news.xml");
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            Map<String, String> news = new HashMap<>();
            if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
                news = printNote(doc.getChildNodes());
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entries : news.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entries.getKey() + entries.getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> printNote(NodeList nodeList) {
        String newsTitle = "", newsDate = "";
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {
                Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

                if (tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                    newsTitle = tempNode.getTextContent();
                else if (tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("date"))
                    newsDate = tempNode.getTextContent();

                data.put(newsDate, newsTitle);

                if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                    printNote(tempNode.getChildNodes());
                }
            }
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entries : data.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entries.getKey() + entries.getValue());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return data;
    }
    }
```

On executing the above code, I am getting following result:

```
Root element :allnews



I am news 1  
04-01-2018I am news 1  



I am news 2  
04-01-2018I am news 2
```

All the unnecessary spaces are also getting put in the map, I want it to be filled only if there is data.

On printing the contents of the `data` map, I get the below:

```
{=}  
{=}  
{=}  
{=I am news 1, 04-01-2018=I am news 1}  
{=}  
{=}  
{=}  
{=I am news 2, 04-01-2018=I am news 2}  
{=}  
{=}
```

Comment: Check your Method printNote ... the data.put happens at every iteration, regardless if data is found or not ... thus the spaces ... also data is initialized at every method invocation, so it'll fail if tempNode actually had ChildNodes ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey try this out please:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XMLParsin {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        File file = new File("Your Example");
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = 
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
        System.out.println("Root element :" + d doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        Map<String, String> news = new HashMap<>();
        if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {
            news = printNote(doc.getChildNodes());
        }


        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entries : news.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entries.getKey() + entries.getValue());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static Map<String, String> printNote(NodeList nodeList) {
    String newsTitle = "", newsDate = "";
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {
            Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

            if (tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                newsTitle = tempNode.getTextContent();
            if (tempNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("date"))
                newsDate = tempNode.getTextContent();


            if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {
                printNote(tempNode.getChildNodes());
            }
        }
        if(!newsDate.isEmpty() && !newsTitle.isEmpty()){
            data.put(newsDate, newsTitle);
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entries : data.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entries.getKey() + entries.getValue());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


    return data;
}
```

}

The main point is you should add one more if section to check whether your information is empty or not. You want to retrieve data only if it is not empty.

I hope this is the solution that you want.The output is :

```
Root element :allnews
04-01-2018I am news 1
04-01-2018I am news 2
```